# interpretation iso-8859-1

Tags: android, character-encoding

Good morning, I came across a problem that I do not understand, let me explain:

I'm working on a project based on microcontroller Arduino and an Android app.
The arduino recovers mails from pop3 commands and sends them to the Android application.
The two communicate through SMS only.

The problem is :
I get messages on Android via SMS Broadcaster to recover then a string (String).

Here is an example of mail recovered object:

> Re: [Stage] techniques =?iso-8859-1?Q?vari?= =?iso-8859-1?B?6WVz?=de communication

This gives the following result:

> Re: [Stage] techniques variées de communication

It may be noted that only some pieces of text are coded in ISO, in two different ways it seems.

My question is:
How can i parse the text ? 
The problem is that using the SMS transmission I did not choose the type of return.
Here is the code I use to read a text message:

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] message = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        String messageBody = null;
        String phoneNumber = null;
        for (int i=0; i< message.length;i++) {

            message[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
        }
        messageBody = message[0].getMessageBody();
        phoneNumber = message[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
        if (message.length > -1) {
            if (phoneNumber.equals(arduino)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "New Data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                //this.abortBroadcast();
                Log.d("BroadcastSMS", "***************phoneNumber:"+phoneNumber+" messageBody:"+messageBody);
                //TODO : ici, que faire du message "messageBody" pour l'interpréter.
            }
        }
    }
```

I find myself already with a message as a String.
My instinct was to try to code myself a "shell" but I do not understand how are coded "ed" in this example.
Clarify my questions are:

- What is the difference between 'Q' and 'B' in the tag ISO?
- In my example the second tag should ISO code "ed" (note the space, if the words are glued). But I'm not in a case of correspondence between a hexadecimal code [0-F] [0-F] for the text is: 6WVz

But I may be on the wrong way,
if you have an answer to these questions or an other method can you help me ?

Thank you in advance anyway.

JM

Answer (score 0):

It is [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) encoded-word. `Q` designates quoted-printable encoding while `B` is for base64.

Comment: Gratitude ! Indeed i can use android.util.Base64 to decode that.